# How can I get content value from meta tag using PyQuery?

Tags: python, pyquery

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Ruby On Rails (Software), Authentication (Software Genre), Tutorial (Industry), howto, tips, tricks">
```

How can I get `content` value from this meta tag using PyQuery?

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

def get_data(myurl):
    query = PyQuery(url=myurl)
    title = query("title").text()
    keyword = query("meta[name=keywords]").text()
    ...
```

Comment: `query("meta[name=keywords]")[0].attr('content')`? Does this work?(http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/attributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You've almost made it, missing apostrophe character to set the `keywork`

```
keyword = query("meta[name='keywords']").text()
```